# Combine TensorFlow Object Detection API with Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, object, keras, detection

TensorFlow version: 1.14
Python version: 3.6.9

My purpose is to build an object detection system with classification. I used Object Detection API and I want to feed its output bounding boxes to another neural networks (there are 6 different objects to detect and then I want to classify these object with Keras neural networks by object's features).

When I use Object Detection API only its OK, but if I want to use model.predict() script crashes. As I've read there's a problem with graph and sessions.

I'm pretty fresh to all these stuff, so I want to ask: is this possible to use multiple models simultaneously?

I've read about creating two sessions and graphs but the input of Object Detection model is a live video from the webcam and I don't want to lose performance of a script. I tried to start session with each frame, but it's very slow.

Also maybe upgrading script to Tensorflow 2.0 will be helpful?

EDIT:

I want to detect fruits and pass them to another Keras models which will predict their state. Detecting fruits works good, but I cannot use additional Keras model, because of the following error:

```
Tensor Tensor("dense_3/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Code provided:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf

import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

from keras import models
from keras.preprocessing import image


import cv2
if 'cap' in globals():
      cap.release() 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

sys.path.append("..")

graph = tf.get_default_graph()

from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

def limit(value, max_val, min_val):
    if(value > max_val):
        value = max_val
    elif(value < min_val):
        value = min_val      
    return value

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'training/labelmap.pbtxt'
NUM_CLASSES = 6

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

def load_image_into_numpy_array_updated(image):
  return np.array(image).astype(np.uint8)

# PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
# TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)


# Loading a keras model
model = models.load_model('new_banana.h5')

with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        while True:
            ret, image_np = cap.read()
            # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
            image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
            # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
            boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
            # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
            # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
            scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
            classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
            num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
            # Actual detection.
            (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
              [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
              feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

            image_np_copy = image_np.copy()
            # Visualization of the results of a detection.
            vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np,
                np.squeeze(boxes),
                np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                np.squeeze(scores),
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                line_thickness=8,
                min_score_thresh=0.7)

            # Code what are used to get thresholded bounding boxes from image
            # enlarge them about compenser value, limitates them
            # print them and send them to another script
            # 0 - apple, 2 - banana, 3 - orange, 4 - pear, 5 - pepper, 6 - tomato
            min_score_thresh = 0.7
            bboxes = boxes[scores > min_score_thresh]
            bclasses = classes[scores > min_score_thresh]

            image_np_new = cv2.resize(image_np_copy, (800,600))
            im_width, im_height = (800, 600)

            if bclasses.size > 0:
                final_box = []
                cropped_images = []
                compenser = 30
                if(bclasses[0] == 2): #if any of detected classes stands for 'banana'
                    for box in bboxes:
                        ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box
                        ymin0 = int(im_height * ymin) - compenser
                        ymax0 = int(im_height * ymax) + compenser
                        xmin0 = int(im_width * xmin) - compenser
                        xmax0 = int(im_width * xmax) + compenser

                        ymin1 = limit(ymin0, im_height, 0)
                        ymax1 = limit(ymax0, im_height, 0)
                        xmax1 = limit(xmax0, im_width, 0)
                        xmin1 = limit(xmin0, im_width, 0)

                        image_cropped = image_np_new[ymin1:ymax1, xmin1:xmax1]
                        height, width, _ = image_cropped.shape

                        if width > height:
                            image_cropped = cv2.resize(image_cropped, (200, 150))
                            image_cropped = cv2.rotate(image_cropped, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
                        else:
                            image_cropped = cv2.resize(image_cropped, (150, 200))

                        image_cropped = load_image_into_numpy_array_updated(image_cropped)
                        image_cropped = image_cropped.reshape((1,) + image_cropped.shape)
                        image_cropped = image_cropped/255
                        cropped_images.append(image_cropped)

                    if (len(cropped_images) > 0):
                        for image in cropped_images:
                            print(image.shape)
                            # input tensor 200, 150, 3
                            classes = model.predict_classes(image, batch_size=10)
                            print(classes)


            cv2.imshow('object detection', image_np)
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                cap.release()
                break
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried and the outputs you got?  and the outputs you expected? There's not enough information in the question to actually answer it

Comment: I edited question with code and more explanation of problem.

Comment: OK, I added K.set_session(sess) in beggining of the loop and in case. I added also loading a model only if needed in a case - it works, but loading model from the beggining every time when it's needed ruins the performance